# How To Perform Navigation In Silverlight 4.0 Using MVVM?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, silverlight-4.0, navigation

I'm new to Silverlight and I'm having trouble understanding how to properly navigate between pages, especially when I need to pass data around.

Classic example: I have a list of People on one page, and when I click on a person in the datagrid I'd like to go to the details page and load that data. I need to pass the PersonId. More importantly, I need to know how to do this from the ViewModel.

It's easy to fire a command from the datagrid that is on the ViewModel, and the SelectedItem on the viewmodel is also bound and thus tracked, but then what? How do I get to the next page? I can't for the life of me figure this one out. This seems like it should be really easy, but so far it's been anything but easy.

Comment: Have you already taken a look at the navigation capabilities in Silverlight (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245(VS.95).aspx) Are you only using MVVM or are you using something like Prism as well?

Comment: Only using MVVM Murven. I more or less figured this out. Seems I either have to inject the NavigationService into the ViewModel from the View, or I have to fire an event from the ViewModel back to the view so it can trigger the call to the NavigationService. But either way it works.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic thing to do would be to change what `Application.Current.RootVisual` is set to and set the appropriate `DataContext`. However it is much better to have some wrappers that set this up properly for you. For example in your custom view that you are navigating to you can have the view's constructor handle some of that logic for you in a nicer way. If you are using Prism then you are ultimately talking about modifying the shell, or a container within the shell.

Comment: Actually, once it is set, Application.Current.RootVisual cannot be changed, but the idea you are trying to transmit is exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

In the SelectedItemChanged you could set a ViewModel property "SelectedItem" with the object that you need in the other page.  You ViewModel would need to be a Singleton.  In the other page, you need to have the DataContext set to the ViewModel and now you can bind the SelectedItem to the control that you want.

The only thing that I do not like is that you still would need to go to the code behind of the starting page, get the SelectedItem from the DataGrid and set the ViewModel with this value.